# Retrun keys that represent different values at two dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to compare two dictionaries that represent  -  pairs. It looks something like that:

```
#pseudo-code, syntax is irrevelant

old_dictionary = {
1241:{
'name': 'Anakin',
'last_name': 'Skywalker',},

1215:{
'name':'someotherguy',
}
}

new_dictionary = {
1241:{
'name':'Darth',
'last_name':'Vader'
}
}
```

What i want is to write a function that will return information about differences between sets. I got comparing by keys with difference of sets created by keys, but have no idea how to effectivly compare two dictionaries by value. Result of this function will be later used to update SQL Database, so i would love to receive result like a dictionaries with changes:

```
{1241:'UPDATE', 1215:'DELETE'}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Of course i can try direct comparision by iterating in this dictionary, but im afraid it would take forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
old_dictionary = {
1241:{
'name': 'Anakin',
'last_name': 'Skywalker',},

1215:{
'name':'someotherguy',
}
}
new_dictionary = {
1241:{
'name':'Darth',
'last_name':'Vader'
}
}

def compare(old_dictionary, new_dictionary):
    result = {}
    for key in old_dictionary:
        if key in new_dictionary:
            if old_dictionary[key] == new_dictionary[key]:
                result[key] = 'NO CHANGE'
            else :
                result[key] = 'UPDATE'
        else :
            result[key] = 'DELETE'
    return result

In [1] : print(compare(old_dictionary, new_dictionary))
Out[1] : {1241: 'UPDATE', 1215: 'DELETE'}
```

Comment: In the end i did the same, but i hoped for a more pythonic way.